# NSData returns <>

Tags: ios, nsdata, initwithcontentsofurl

I am converting url data into `UIImage`. This is my code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSLog(@"Image Error-------%@",[error localizedDescription]);
imgProf = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

but My data always returns `<>`

```
(lldb) po data
<>
```

But when I type this url in browser I can get the image. What is the reason for this? 
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: No error raised? What's the URL? Have you signed into the website?

Comment: error returns null. And yeas after Iloging I call to this method to get the user profile  image

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty response because your code (app) can't authenticate with the server by the sounds of it. This should generally be returned as an error but it depends on the response from the server.

You need to deal with the authentication first, so the app has an auth token or cookie or something and then you can make your request (potentially supplying the auth details in headers).

Comment: for other details I want to pass authorization tokens with the header. but for image they said I can just get it. And they said I should be able to get the image even just click from the browser url.

Comment: Test in incognito mode in chrome

Comment: it loads an empty page